# Using SweetAlert2 as popup on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I am trying to use [**SweetAlert2**](https://sweetalert2.github.io/) as a "popup box" once the page finishes loading. Underneath the "popup box" overlay is normal content.

- The "popup box" will have **2 links** that the visitor can click on.(**clicking outside the box will not close the popup**)
- Upon clicking on **any one of the link**, it will **open a respective new tab**
- If it detects visitor **clicked on both links**, **it will unlock and redirect itself to another page**.

How can I achieve this?

**Reference:**

> [How to add event listener for html buttons in sweetalert dialog box in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35307133/how-to-add-event-listener-for-html-buttons-in-sweetalert-dialog-box-in-jquery)
>
> ```
> `http://codepen.io/html5andblog/pen/jPzPWj` (this is good but it doesn't onload and redirect)
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your homework ;) **[[JSFIDDLE]](https://jsfiddle.net/oarpyd0s/2/)**

```
swal({
  html: 
    '<a href="http://example1.com" id="link1" target="_blank">link 1</a><br>' + 
    '<a href="http://example2.com" id="link2" target="_blank">link 2</a>',
  confirmButtonText: 'Continue >',
  allowOutsideClick: false,
  allowEscapeKey: false
});

// disable "Continue >" button on load
swal.disableButtons();

// handle clicks and enable "Continue >" button when all links are clicked
var clickedLinks = [];
$('body').on('click', '.swal2-modal a', function(e) {
  var link = e.target;
  if (clickedLinks.indexOf(link) === -1) {
    clickedLinks.push(link);
  }
  // when all links are clicked enable "Continue >" button
  if (clickedLinks.length === $('.swal2-modal a').size()) {
    swal.enableButtons();
  }
});
```

Comment: OMG, this is freaking awesome bro! :D

Comment: Thank you so much bro :D
I tried loading it just by putting the script in the body, it loads well on PC,
but it doesn't load on mobile. 
Should i put something like <body onload= ... 
Am i doing it wrongly?

Comment: Yes, it's weird that pc is fine but doesnt load on iphone and andriod that i tried just now.
i tried using the script on 2 different host using wordpress but same result. =/
i went to your https://limonte.github.io/sweetalert2/ on mobile and it works on there. 
do i need to place the script using special parameters or in specific section? im not sure what's causing it not to load =/

Comment: i tried 3 of my mobile(iphone and 2 andriod-chrome browser), all doesnt load on my website, but strangely when it loads your github.io, there it is fine.
asked a few person to test it and it loads for them.. and a programmer i asked quote me $50 to fix this.. =(

Comment: Change `$('body').on('click', '.swal2-modal a', (e) => {`, to `$('body').on('click', '.swal2-modal a', function(e) {`, I've updated my answer and jsfiddle

Comment: hey limonte , merry christmas! btw could you help me with this too?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41320633/using-sweetalert2-as-exit-intent-opt-in-form
Thanks a million