# Angular2 - Sweetalert custom button click doesn´t work

Tags: angular, sweetalert2

I create a custom button inside a footer in **Sweetalert2** like this.

```
    Swal.fire({
          icon: "question",
          showCancelButton: true,
          confirmButtonColor: "#1976d2",
          cancelButtonText: "No",
          confirmButtonText: "Sí",
          footer: "<button (click)='withoutread()' class='btn btn-info'>Test</button>"
  })

  withoutread() {
    console.log('hello');
  }
```

The problem: The function `withoutread` doesn´t call properly, `console.log('hello')` doesn´t show **hello** in console.

So: What´s wrong in this code?

Comment: afaik (click) is angular syntax, and angular does not recompile the code therefore it will not work.  Not sure if plain js onclick function would work though.

Comment: Try putting button within anchor tag  `<a><button (click)='withoutread()' class='btn btn-info'>Test</button></a>`

Comment: You can refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39268318/more-than-2-buttons-on-sweetalert-2

Answer (score 1):

**Working !**

```
Swal.fire({
  icon: 'error',
  title: 'Oops...',
  text: 'Something went wrong!',
  footer: '<button id="buttonId">Test</button>'
})

document.getElementById('buttonId').onclick = function(){
    alert('do Something');
}
```

Comment: Inside that onclick handler, how can we access any typescript variable?

Comment: Just pass the variable in function document.getElementById('buttonId').onclick = function(var1 , var2){//body}

Comment: Those are variables within the event scope. Can a JS event handler access the typescript local and instance variables? For example, 
`sampleFunction(traceId){`

Swal.fire({
  icon: 'error',
  title: 'Oops...',
  text: 'Something went wrong!',
  footer: '<button id="buttonId">Test</button>'
})

`document.getElementById('buttonId').onclick = function(){
    //May I know how I can access the traceId local variable here?
}`
}

Answer (score 0):

Your click method in the way you have implemented it would not be accessible since the method `withoutread()` exists outside of the scope of the SweetAlert instance.

Aside from the SweetAlert [configurations available](https://sweetalert2.github.io/#input-types) for capturing user input, you could include a third, custom button and capture the click using event delegation as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35307202/2934896)

Comment: I want to add a third button to sweetalert2 modal, so this it doesn´t is that i need.

Comment: It would be possible using event delegation. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
footer: "<a><button (click)='withoutread()' class='btn btn-info'>Test</button></a>"
```

**OR**

```
footer: "<a onclick='withoutread()'><button class='btn btn-info'>Test</button></a>"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to user onclick rather than (click). Please look at the below working code.

```
Swal.fire({
      icon: "question",
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonColor: "#1976d2",
      cancelButtonText: "No",
      confirmButtonText: "Sí",
      footer: "<button onclick='withoutread()' class='btn btn-info'>Test</button>"
})
 function withoutread() {
     alert('dd') 
 }
```

You can also review the JSFiddle link
[here](https://jsfiddle.net/w2nryduj/)